# trouble signing on android

Tags: android

I'm trying to sign an app made in Processing so I can test it on other phones, without having to attach them.

However the signing is giving me some problems.

- I created a keystore with keytool, placed it in the right place
- I built with ant, an '...-unsigned.apk' file appeared
- I used jarsigner: `jarsigner  -verbose -keystore myapp.keystore bin/myapp-unsigned.apk myappalias`

Here's the output of jarsigner:

```
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
 updating: META-INF/JOONPONG.SF
 updating: META-INF/JOONPONG.RSA
  signing: assets/crash.mp3
  signing: assets/paddle.mp3
  signing: assets/wall1.mp3
  signing: assets/wall2.mp3
  signing: assets/wall3.mp3
  signing: res/drawable/icon.png
  signing: res/layout/main.xml
  signing: AndroidManifest.xml
  signing: resources.arsc
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
  signing: res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
  signing: classes.dex
```

It shows no error message of any kind.
The passphrase is correct, reassuring me that my key is working. However, the APK file remains unchanged. I can't find a 'myapp_signed.apk' anywhere.

Where do I start looking? All information I find just seems to work right after doing jarsigner, but it doesn't here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be JDK 7 not playing nice. I read somewhere to use JDK 6, I downgraded, and everything worked.

It cost me several hours to figure this out, I hope this info can be useful for somebody else. I have no idea what the cause is for the JDK 7 bugs.